# How to Calculate Sales From Other Key Figures?

Tags: fundamentals

Regarding https://www.quandl.com/data/SF1-Core-US-Fundamentals-Data/documentation/indicators

I would like to get the ***sales*** of a company retrieved.

How can this be determined?

Comment: um... revenues are sales, bro.

Comment: I found this [http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/122214/what-difference-between-revenue-and-sales.asp](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/122214/what-difference-between-revenue-and-sales.asp) article which mentions a difference between the two terms

Comment: The difference is semantic. Sharadars definition for Revenues is "Amount of Revenue recognized from goods sold, services rendered, insurance premiums, or other activities that constitute an earning process. Interest income for financial institutions is reported net of interest expense and provision for credit losses." If you need further granularity than that, you're going to have to reference another data source.

Answer (score -2):

It is calculated as:

```
sales = 
      REVENUEUSD        (Revenues (USD))
   minus
      ROIC              (Retun on Invested Capital)
   minus
      ROA               (Return on Average Assets)
   minus
      ROE               (Return on Average Equity)
```