# How to calculate sales value from financial statement

Tags: equities

I need to calculate Sales from Revenue and other metrics available in financial statements provided by publicly traded companies.

Specifically I need to reproduce the metric available named **Sales Q/Q** at finviz.com, or named **Revenue Change % - MRQ 1 Yr. Ago** at Interactive Brokers trading platform. These are the same values, validated over a few stocks.

My problem is that financial statements only contain **TotalRevenue**, but not **Sales**.

There is this question but the only answer is not really usable:
[How to Calculate Sales From Other Key Figures?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34046/how-to-calculate-sales-from-other-key-figures)

To summarize: I need to calculate Sales value from quarterly financial statements and maybe cash flow statements.

Comment: In everyday parlance Revenue and Sales are the same thing. What accounting items  that could bring about a difference between Revenue and Sales are you particularly concerned about?

Comment: Is it about the different between Gross Sales vs Net Sales? For example, the value of merchandise sold on Ebay would be Gross sales, whereas the marketplace commission would be Net sales.

Comment: I would like to calculate with gross sales, vales which are related to the company's core business. Income related to investments for example needs to be excluded. The main thing is, that Interactive Brokers and FinViz calculates this metric in the same way an I need to replicate this calculation.